# Axios & Typescript promise rejection error has type unkown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, try-catch, unhandled-promise-rejection

The problem I'm currently facing is that I can't use a returned error from a promise rejection because it is not typeable with Typescript. For example when a signup request fails because the username is already taken I return a `400` with the `message` `username already taken`. But I can't access the message from the error because the `error` object from a `try catch` can't be typed.
Is there any way axios can handle this situation and can give me access to the error obejct with a custom type?
Or should I just create an error object under the data and either return it as `null` when the server has a `200` or return an error obejct?

Example:

```js
export interface ErrorRes {
  statusCode: number;
  error: string;
  message: string;
}

export interface ISignupRes {
  token: string;
  user: IUser;
  message: string;
}
```

```js
const handleSignUp = async () => {
  setLoading(true)
  try {
    const { data, status }: { data: ISignupRes; status: number } =
      await coreApi.post('/auth/signup', {
        email,
        username,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        password,
      })
    if (status === 200) {
      Storage.save(true, 'token', data.token)
      addNotification({
        type: 'success',
        message: data.message,
      })
    } else {
      // this never get's called because if the response returns an error it get's catched
      addNotification({
        type: 'error',
        message: data.message,
      })
    }
    setLoading(false)
  } catch (error) {
    // the error is of type `unkown` to I can't access `error.message`
    setLoading(false)
    addNotification({
      type: 'error',
      message: error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't have a way to verify that axios errors are the only possible errors that could be thrown by your code, so the error in a typescript catch block is always either `unknown` or `any`. Your compiler settings apparently prefer `unknown`.

To treat the error as something else you either need to put in some code to check what type of thing was thrown, or you need to use a type assertion to insist to typescript that you know what the type is. Fortunately, the axios library includes a helper function that can do the check for you, and it has appropriate types to narrow down the error object:

```
} catch (error) {
  if (axios.isAxiosError(error) {
    // inside this block, typescript knows that error's type is AxiosError<any>
    setLoading(false)
    addNotification({
      type: 'error',
      message: error.message,
    })
  } else {
    // In this block, error is still of type `unknown`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that I found to be helpful for *typing* the Axios error that I found [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3612#issuecomment-1198490390) by user btraut:

Add this:

```
export function isAxiosError<ResponseType>(error: unknown): error is AxiosError<ResponseType> {
  return axios.isAxiosError(error);
}
```

and then use the following by replacing the *MyExpectedResponseType* with the Type you'd like your error object to be.

```
type MyExpectedResponseType = {
  thisIsANumber: number;
};

try {
  // Make the axios fetch.
} catch (error: unknown) {
  if (isAxiosError<MyExpectedResponseType>(error)) {
    // "thisIsANumber" is properly typed here:
    console.log(error.response?.data.thisIsANumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a response interceptor to wrap a try-catch block for every request.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (error) => {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        throw new HttpRequestError("Request Failed: " + error.response?.data);
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    });
```